# Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled

Tags: google-api, google-console-developer

I am attempting an Exchange to Gmail conversion. First steps are to open developer and then create a service project. I get a Google Cloud Platform service has been disabled error right away. The Cloud Platform is enabled on my system, and Google support has verified. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in Firefox and tried it on Chrome. It got me to the sign up and give payment info page, which is farther than I got on Firefox.

Comment: Similar issue here, failed on Safari and works in Chrome